# Insert into one table, get id and insert into another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to check if a `string` exist in a table, say `Table1`. If yes, get the `id` of the string in the table (id is an `Identity` column, which automatically increases its value). If no add the string as new row to the table and get the `id`.

Then insert data into another table, say `Table2`, get the `id` of the new data in the `Table2` and update `Table1`.

My situation is :

The user can upload images with tags. When the user click `upload` button first check if the `tag` exist in the `table Tags`. Get the `tag id` . Needed it for the `AssociatedTags` column in `table Images`.

Then get the `image id` and update `AssociatedImages` column in `table Tags`.

OR If I am doing it all wrong and there is another way to do this please point me.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is what i did for inserting new row into database

```
SqlConnection SConn = new SqlConnection();
SConn .ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my_Connection"].ConnectionString;
SConn .Open();
using (SqlCommand SComm = new SqlCommand())
{
    SComm .Connection = SConn ;
    SComm .CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SComm .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images (Title,Category,TagIds) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3)";
    SComm .Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", title.Text);
    SComm .Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", Category.Text);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tags.Text))
        SComm .Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", DBNull.Value);
    else
        SComm .Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", Tags.Text);
}
```

Comment: You are asking for C# code right? Querying from SQL server by C#?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: Yes, I need c# code. I don't know much about these sql and c#. This my first project.

Answer (score 2):

```
   i think it is better to make procedure like this

 create procedure insertimage
  (@title mvarchar(50),
   @category nvarchar(50),
  @tagtxt  nvarchar(50)
 )
   as
 declare @tagid int
 if exists(select tagid from tags where tagtxt=@tagtxt)
begin
set @tagid=(select tagid from tags where tagtxt=@tagtxt)
 insert into image (title,category,tagid)values(@title,@category,@tagid)
 end
else
begin
insert into tags(tagtxt)values(@tagtxt)
 set @tagid=(SCOPE_IDENTITY())
 insert into image (title,category,tagid)values(@title,@category,@tagid)
end

    and in c#

 sqlcommand scomm=new sqlcommand("insertimages",sconn)
 scomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  scomm.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = title.text;
        scomm.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = category.Text;
    scomm.Parameters.Add("@tagtxt", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tags.text;
 sconn.open();
 scomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your sql to this:

```
INSERT INTO Images (Title,Category,TagIds) VALUES (@val1, @val2, @val3); Select Scope_Identity()
```

Then:

```
int ID = (int)SComm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 to banksy (I don't have sufficient reputation to make this a comment) - do database stuff in the database.

I would suggest putting the body of the stored procedure in a transaction:

```
create procedure insertimage
  (@title mvarchar(50),
   @category nvarchar(50),
  @tagtxt  nvarchar(50)
 )
   as
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 declare @tagid int
 ...
 ...
 insert into image (title,category,tagid)values(@title,@category,@tagid)
end
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
-- Add any error processing
END CATCH
```

The lines in upper case are new. Case is not important.

The reason for the transaction is that, if anything goes wrong, everything is rolled-back (i.e. undone). You are not left with (for example) a row in `image` without a row in `tags`.